# How do you set up Windows Ads in Windows 8.1 MonoGame Store apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, monogame

I'm using MonoGame to create a Windows Store game based on sprites but when I right-click my project and [try to add pubCenter integration in as a connected service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn284011%28v=msads.10%29.aspx) it doesn't have the option to add any connected services.

That being said, how would you add pubCenter Windows Ads in to MonoGame applications?

[I am using Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013, with the latest Advertising SDK extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-windows-prereqs%28v=msads.10%29.aspx) installed correctly on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, looks like I forgot to set my project's Target Platform Version to Windows 8.1! Hope this helps other people out; the latest build (as of right now) enables your platform to only Windows 8 by default.